# Always Block in Verilog executes every time

Tags: verilog, fpga

I've been having problem just figuring out this simple code.

```
module diode(switch,led);
output led;
input switch;
reg led;
always@*
begin
led=1'b0;
end
endmodule
```

The logic behind it is as follow = press the button, the LED turns on?

Now the problem I am facing is this always block. The way it's supposed to work is that whenever there's a change in switch(the button that I press), the LED should turn on? But the LED turns on automatically all the time enterting this Always block even if I don't press anything? The only way to 'solve' this is if I put an if/else statements in always block so that LED has a default value(when it's not turned on).

My main question is: Why does LED get the value 1'b0 (turning it on) when I'm not even pressing any buttons on my FPGA board?

I tried to give base value to LED at the beginning and even with this code:

```
module diode(switch,led);
output led;
input switch;
reg led=1'b0;
always@*
begin
led = 1'b1;
end
endmodule
```

the LED always stays OFF because of what's written in the always block. What's the catch that I'm not getting here? Why is it behaving like this?

Any  help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You never USE switch! How is it supposed to control something if you not even use it. Yes, it is defined as an input but you never refer to it in any way.

Comment: Assigning 0 to `led` does not depend on `switch` signal in your code.

Comment: Why does it enter always block then? The solution to my problem is fairly simple if I put if/else statements and check if the button is pressed but doesn't always block do that for me? Doesn't that block trigger ONLY if switch is pressed? Or is the debouncing problem and it things that SWITCH is pressed anyway without physically pressing it by myself? Thank you for both for answering!

Comment: It does NOT enter the always block. Inside the always block you never mention `switch`.  `input switch;` means that `switch` it is a signal coming into the module "diode". I suggest you have a look at existing Verilog code.

Comment: Why does the LED diode turn on in the first case if it's not entering the ALWAYS block?

(led=1'b0 is for turning ON the LED and it triggers it?)

Comment: My question is this: If always block triggers when I press something and I in case when I don't press anything it doesn't go into that always block, why does LED turn on based off of that code led=1'b0. If I set in my always block 
led=1'b1 the LED won't turn off which means it depends on the code INSIDE the always block. That's what's confusing me deeply :/

Answer (score 0):

verilog is designed for 'event-driven' simulation. This means that every always block (and other blocks) are executed only when an input event happens. Signal value change or an edge constitute an event which trigger the execution of the block.

In classical verilog, for always blocks, the event triggering signals are listed in the sensitivity lists. in v2k, `always @*` is supposed to figure out all the inputs from the code contained withing the block.

In your case the always block has **no** inputs, so it should never be executed. The `switch` is never been used in the always block. There are no other inputs, besides the constant, which cannot change and cannot trigger the event.

you need to provide some logic which would use your `switch` in order to make it functional, i.e.

```
always @*
    led = ~switch;
```

It will turn your led on while switch is '1' (pushed), then it will turn it off. If you need a more complicated logic, you should work on it. if you want to toggle the state of the led by pressing the switch, you would need to create a small state machine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough explanation, my biggest problem is that as explained in my comment above, LED behaves depending on my always block (that takes input from me based off of the switch). 

As stated in the comment above:  If always block triggers when I press something and I in case when I don't press anything it doesn't go into that always block, why does LED turn on based off of that code led=1'b0. If I set in my always block led=1'b1 the LED won't turn off which means it depends on the code INSIDE the always block.

Comment: @NurdinIbrišimović that means that there is more code which is relevant to the case and which you had not shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The below code would work

```
module diode(input  switch,
             output led);

  assign led = (switch)?(1'b0):(1'b1); //Since 1'b0 switches the LED on.

endmodule
```